# Pontoon game lost in the code

Tags: java

So here is the thing. i started to look in to the simple java programming. and got to the point where covered all of the simple lessons and alredy know how to do some of easy coding. the trouble i have is with using all of my covered knowledge in one code. I wanted to create a game as i been told taht it is possible, i think they are doing it on the actual lessons of java. though i have encountered some problems. It is working BUT it dosent stops when the players hand rises over 24 points. where in game the player should be bust it keeps asking do u want another card? i have used the if statement but it dosent seem to notice it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pontoon{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int playerScore = 0, computerScore = 0;
    String newCard = "";
    playerScore += dealCard();
    computerScore += dealCard();
    playerScore += dealCard();
    computerScore += dealCard();

    System.out.printf("Your score is %d would you like another card ? y/n ", playerScore);
    newCard = input.nextLine();
    if(newCard.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
        while (newCard.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && playerScore < 21) { 
            playerScore += dealCard();
            System.out.printf("Your score is %d would you like another card ? y/n ", playerScore);
            newCard = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    while(computerScore < 15){
        computerScore += dealCard();
    }
    checkWin(playerScore, computerScore);
}
public static int dealCard(){
    int value = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;
    int score = 0;
    if(value == 1) {
        System.out.println("Ace!");
        score = 11;
    }else if (value == 13) {
        System.out.println("King!");
        score = 10;
    }else if (value == 12) {
        System.out.println("Queen!");
        score = 10;
    } else if (value == 11) {
        System.out.println("Jack!");
        score = 10;
    } else {
        score = value;
    }

    return score;
}

public static void checkWin(int Player, int Computer) {
    int player = Player;
    int computer = Computer;

    if (player > 21) {
        System.out.println("Player Bust");
    } else if (computer > 21) {
        System.out.println("Computer Bust");
    } else {
        if (player > computer) {
            System.out.println("Player Wins!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to take your lessons to a new step.  You've started coding, now you need to start _debugging_.  It's time to step through your code in a debugger, watch the states of the relevant objects, and determine where it deviates from expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

On your while loop:

```
while (newCard.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
```

add a condition to check the player score

```
while (newCard.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && playerScore < 21) {
```

Comment: i have chengad as u sad and now it gives me the output as @player bust@. i also want to do the output for the computer hand but could not find the right output command. can you plese give me a hand./?

Comment: hmm also when i am trying to write System.out.println it gives me the error but when i leave f i nthe end of print it works i want it to create new line but it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

well i have done it and here is the output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pontoon{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int playerScore = 0, computerScore = 0;
        String newCard = "";
        playerScore += dealCard();
        computerScore += dealCard();
        playerScore += dealCard();
        computerScore += dealCard();

        System.out.printf("Your score is %d would you like another card ? y/n ", playerScore);
        newCard = input.nextLine();
        if(newCard.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            while (newCard.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && playerScore < 21) { 
                playerScore += dealCard();
                System.out.printf("Your score is %d would you like another card ? y/n ", playerScore);
                newCard = input.nextLine();
            }
        } while(computerScore < 15){
            computerScore += dealCard();
        }
        checkWin(playerScore, computerScore);
    }
    public static int dealCard(){
        int value = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        int score = value;
        System.out.println(+value);
        if(value == 11) {
            System.out.println("Ace!");
            score = 11;
        }else if (value == 10) {
            System.out.println("King!");
            score = 10;
        }else if (value == 10) {
            System.out.println("Queen!");
            score = 10;
        } else if (value == 10) {
            System.out.println("Jack!");
            score = 10;
        } else {
            score = value;
        }

        return score;
    }

    public static void checkWin(int Player, int Computer) {
        int player = Player;
        int computer = Computer;

        System.out.printf("computer score is score is %d  ", Computer);
        if (player > 21) {
            System.out.println("     Player Bust");
        } else if (computer > 21) {
            System.out.println("     Computer Bust,Player Wins");
        } else {
            if (player > computer) {
                System.out.println("    Player Wins!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("    Computer Wins!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```